# Why 2 docs with a single word returns 0.00 for similarity?

Tags: spacy

Why the code below gives me 0.00 for similarity with both docs having the same word astronaut?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.en.English()
print (nlp('astronaut').similarity(nlp('astronaut')))
# Result: 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that word vectors for single terms are points, and you cannot get [cosine distance similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between points.

See the vector comparison for multi dimensional vectors vs points :

```
>>> a = nlp(u'astronaut eating apple banana cherry')
>>> b = nlp(u'astronaut eating apple banana fruit')
>>> a.similarity(b)
0.96363932891327542
>>> a.similarity(a)
0.99999997666693974
>>> b.similarity(b)
1.000000996690289
>>> a = nlp(u'astronaut')
>>> b = nlp(u'astronaut')
>>> a.similarity(a)
0.0
>>> b = nlp(u'cosmonaut')
>>> a.similarity(a)
0.0
>>> b.similarity(b)
0.0
>>> a.similarity(b)
0.0
>>> c = nlp(u'single')
>>> a.similarity(c)
0.0
```